# RequestFactory request (AutoBeanCodexImpl.doCoderFor) never finish and use 100% cpu

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, autobean

We have a GWT application deployed onto tomcat, after a few hours of use (2 QAs perform general testing), java process start to use all CPUs and app become slow.

I looked into tomcat manager and find out there are many long running HTTP requests and they are all pointing to "/gwtRequest" which is our RequestFactory servlet.

After that I took a thread dump and found out that all RUNNABLE http threads in the dump are pointing to "AutoBeanCodexImpl.doCoderFor()"

> ```
> "http-8080-51" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f23d8b81800 nid=0x4981 runnable [0x00007f23d4285000]
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
> at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:303)
> at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AutoBeanCodexImpl.doCoderFor(AutoBeanCodexImpl.java:519)
> at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.setProperty(AbstractAutoBean.java:276)
> at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.ProxyAutoBean.setProperty(ProxyAutoBean.java:253)
> at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.BeanPropertyContext.set(BeanPropertyContext.java:44)
> at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.Resolver$PropertyResolver.visitValueProperty(Resolver.java:155)
> at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.ProxyAutoBean.traverseProperties(ProxyAutoBean.java:289)
> at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.traverse(AbstractAutoBean.java:166)
> at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.accept(AbstractAutoBean.java:101)
> at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.Resolver.resolveClientValue(Resolver.java:414)
> at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.processInvocationMessages(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:493)
> at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:235)
> at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:137)
> at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
> ```

Can someone kindly point me to areas I should look at? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, ouch! It looks like we're using a static `HashMap` without any synchronization! I believe this is because AutoBeans were first designed to work in the browser only, which is single-threaded.

This is [fixed in trunk](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=11268) and it should [make it into 2.5.0-rc2](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/fc_r56Lu4Us/discussion) to be released in a few days. You can track [the issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7667) status.

Comment: May I ask a silly question, if it is synchronization issue, should it cause deadlock, can it also cause endless loop in some circumstances?

Comment: found answer to my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003026/hashmap-concurrency-issue