# Is this thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Is this thread safe? Do I need the lock?

```
public class Load {

    //private final Object lock = new Object();

    private final Map<String, String> confs = new HashMap<String, String>();

   public void addValue(String key, String value) {
       //synchronized (lock)
       confs.put(key, value);

   }

   public String getValue(String key) {
      //synchronized (lock)
      return confs.get(key);
   }
}
```

I think it's thread safe without lock. 
when I do new Load(), there will be new hashmap instance. is this correct?

Comment: It depends how you want to access the Load object (for example if you modify and read only from the event dispatch thread it is ok). Usually this is not thread-safe.

Comment: You should think of ConcurrentHashMap instead of lock in this case.

Comment: Not thread safe.  You have mutable, shared state that's not guarded in any way.

Comment: This is not thread safe .. you shall use ConcurrentHashMap if you want thread safety

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` is not thread-safe by default. If you need thread-safe version, use `ConcurrentHashMap` or you can work with locks manually.

Comment: Thanks. but still <p> when I do new Load(), there will be new hashmap instance. how could two thread come to the map?

Comment: @user3644708 during just constructor call you won't get any problems. But if later you will use `addValue` method of the same `Load` object from different threads, you can get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** thread safe. If two threads call `addValue` at the same time it is very likely that your `HasMap` will become corrupt.

You could fix it by using a [ConcurrentHasMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

See:

[Hashmap concurrency issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003026/823393)

and especially

[A Beautiful Race Condition](http://mailinator.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html)

Here's a demonstration of using your `Load` class that would probably crash horribly.

```
public class Load {

    private final Map<String, String> confs = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void addValue(String key, String value) {
        confs.put(key, value);

    }

    public String getValue(String key) {
        //synchronized (lock)
        return confs.get(key);
    }
}

public class Loader implements Runnable {
    private final Load load;

    public Loader (Load load) {
        this.load = load;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            load.addValue("" + i, "Value:" + i);
        }
    }

}
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    Load load = new Load();
    Loader l1 = new Loader(load);
    Loader l2 = new Loader(load);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(l1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(l2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  when I do new Load(), there will be new hashmap instance. how could two thread come to the map?

Comment: @user3644708 - If the same `Load` object is being used by two threads.

Comment: @user3644708 you ask if the code is thread safe and people are giving valid answers: no it is not. You sketch a situation here where there never will be any risk of collision at all. The code is thread safe when it can safely be used by multiple threads at the same time - that is not the case here. If that is not what you want to know, then change your question.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not thread safe. Try using ConcurrentHashMap

```
public class Load {

    //private final Object lock = new Object();

    private final Map<String, String> confs = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

   public void addValue(String key, String value) {
       //synchronized (lock)
       confs.put(key, value);

   }

   public String getValue(String key) {
      //synchronized (lock)
      return confs.get(key);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not thread safe. You need to put lock in code. Try using ConcurrentHasMap.

Check this [code](http://www.concretepage.com/java/example_concurrenthashmap_java), if you have used normal HashMap, that would give you an exception:

```
package com.concretepage;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
public class ConcurrentHashMapTest implements Runnable{
  private String name;
  private static Map<String,String> conpage=new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
  ConcurrentHashMapTest(String name){
      conpage.put("1","A");
      conpage.put("2","B");
      conpage.put("3","C");
      this.name=name;
  }
  public void run() {
    try{
      Iterator<String> it = conpage.keySet().iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()){
        String key=it.next();
        conpage.put("A"+key, "A"+key);
      }
      System.out.println(name +" completed.");
    }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ExecutorService  executor= Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      executor.execute(new ConcurrentHashMapTest("Thread one"));
      executor.execute(new ConcurrentHashMapTest("Thrad two"));
      executor.shutdownNow();
  }
}
```