# Trying to understand the accepted answer - Thread Safe Map of Queues

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency, thread-safety

[Thread safe Map of Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496437/thread-safe-map-of-queues)

The above question has a design implementation VERY similar to my own. I understand why it's not thread safe, but the accepted "pattern" is throwing me for a loop. I don't quite get how to implement it or what it does in relationship to the question.

```
    boolean send = false;
    System.out.println("MailCenter Size Start: " + mailBox.keySet().size());
    if (parsedInput.size() == 3) {
        for (String s : writers.keySet()) {
            if (!s.equals(parsedInput.get(1))) {
                send = true;
            }
        }
        if (send) {
            mailMessage.add(noAnsiName + ": " + parsedInput.get(2));
            mailBox.putIfAbsent(parsedInput.get(1), mailMessage);
            System.out.println("Current mail message is: " + mailMessage.peek());
            out.println("SERVER You have sent mail to " + parsedInput.get(1) + ".");
        }
        System.out.println("MailCenter Size Middle: " + mailBox.keySet().size());
    } else {
        int loop = 0;
        for (Map.Entry entry : mailBox.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":\t" + entry.getValue());
            System.out.println("*** LOOP STATUS *** " + loop);
            loop++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question, tell us precisely what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: This is one possible application of 'compare-and-swap' pattern. Maybe, Wikipedia article will be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Comment: I'm trying to understand the design pattern, while at the same time solving a specific issue. Edited to include my own code.

Comment: If indenting your code is good, then indenting it more is probably better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't quite get how to implement it or what it does in relationship
>   to the question.

The question shows that a `ConcurrentHashMap` is being used. However, the variable `map` is being declared as a `Map`, so the method `putIfAbsent()` referenced by the accepted answer is not visible.

```
Map<String, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

So, in order for the answer to work, the above must be changed to declare `map` as a `ConcurrentMap`.

Now, that's a good step toward thread safety. However, just because we're using a concurrent map implementation doesn't mean a `get()` and subsequent `put()` on the map are an atomic unit of work. In other words, another thread can still change the state of the map after the current thread calls `get()`, but before it calls `put()`.

The answer recommends [`putIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)) because it *ensures atomicity* by wrapping the equivalent of a `containsKey()` call and a `put()` call in a synchronized block. If you also then use the return value correctly, you will have solid concurrent behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Between this and what I understood already, and taking a fresh look at the pattern, I understand now.

Comment: `putIfAbsent()` is now a default method on `Map` as of Java8