# One HashMap, two threads - how do I ensure thread-safety in this example?

Tags: java, hashmap, thread-safety

I have a question about thread-safety and HashMaps. More specifically, I'm wondering if there's a chance that one thread tries to read from a HashMap while it's being written to. Here's a rough example:

I have a class called "TestClass":

```
public class TestClass implements Runnable {

    // New thread
    TestThread testThread = new TestThread();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // Starts the thread.
        testThread.start();

        // A copy of testHashMap is retrieved from the other thread.
        // This class often reads from the HashMap.
        // It's the only class that reads from the HashMap.
        while (true) {
            HashMap<String, Long> testHashMap = testThread.get();

        }
    }
}
```

And I have another class called TestThread:

```
public class TestThread extends Thread {

    private HashMap<String, Long> testHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // This thread performs a series of calculations once a second.
        // After the calculations are done, they're saved to testHashMap with put().
        // This is the only thread that writes to testHashMap.

    }

    // This method returns a copy of testHashMap. This method is used by the Test class.
    public HashMap<String, Long> get() {
        return testHashMap;
    }

}
```

Is it possible that the get() method will attempt to copy testHashMap while it's being written to by TestThread? And if so, how do I ensure thread-safety in this example? Do I have to create a synchronizedMap instead of a HashMap?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003026/6505250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that the get() method will attempt to copy testHashMap while it's being written to by TestThread?

No. The `get()` method just returns the map. No copying going on here.

But yes, you have to somehow control the access to the map since `HashMap` is not threadsafe. You can achieve this by synchronizing a hashmap (`Map<A, B> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<A, B>());`) or using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.